# PHP IF statement for Boolean values: $var === true vs $var

Tags: php, coding-style, paradigms

I know this question is not really important.. however I've been wondering:

Which of the following IF statements is the best and fastest to use?

```
<?php

$variable = true;

if($variable === true)
{
    //Something
}

if($variable)
{
    // Something
}


?>
```

I know === is to match exactly the boolean value. However is there really any improvement?

Comment: I tried and I can't confirm your claim.

Comment: Old question, so just a brief comment: Testing with strict equality (===) is normally faster, as testing without will incur a performance cost because it does type coercion.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Using `if ($var === true)` or `if ($var)` is not a question of style but a question of correctness. Because `if ($var)` is the same as `if ($var == true)`. And `==` comparison doesn’t check the type. So `1 == true` is true but `1 === true` is false.

Answer (score 12):

As far as speed, I agree with Niels, it's probably negligible.

As far as which if statement is best to test with, the answer probably depends on the expected casting and values $variable can have.

If $variable is using 0 and 1 as a true/false flag then if ( $variable ) or if ( !$variable ) would work, but if it's an integer result as in strpos() you'll run into problems ... if possible, I'd recommend using an actual boolean value rather than 0 / 1.

... maybe this will help clarify; comment out the variations of $var to see the various results.

```
<?php

$var = true;
$var = 1;

$var = false;
$var = 0;

if ( $var ) {
    echo 'var = true <br />';
}

if ( $var === true ) {
    echo 'var is a boolean and = true';
}

if ( !$var ) {
    echo 'var = false <br />';
}

if ( $var === false ) {
    echo 'var is a boolean and = false';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just a fact:

`time php -r '$r = true; for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) { if($r == true) {} }'`

`time php -r '$r = true; for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) { if($r) {} }'`

The second one is faster than the first.

Answer (score 5):

===  is really helpful in strstr/stristr when the first needle is in position 0 in the haystack. If you don't use === or !== you could have a bug on your hands.

```
$str = "four score and...";
$position = strstr($str,'four');
if($position===FALSE) return FALSE;
```

Comment: Small comment on your code: I would always use curly braces {} around a codeblock after an if statement. I know it's not necessary, but imho it's good for readability.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really deep into the technical stuff of PHP, but in the first case

```
if($variable === true)
```

$variable has to have the exact same type as true for the if statement to be true. In other words, $variable has not only to resolve to true, but also has to be a boolean. So that's 2 operations, value-checking and type-checking.

In the second case

```
if($variable)
```

$variable only has to resolve to true. So only value checking occurs. I infer that that takes the computer a little less time.

Practically speaking: the differences in speed are probably negligible.