# How to make true/false statements

Tags: php

*It's not because I want to know how to do this instead of which one is faster..*

How would I make a statement true or false ?

I want this:

```
if $var = true {
    do this
} else{
    do this
}
```

I'm aleady using a `foreach` but I thought something like this:

```
if($myvar == 'True'){
    echo copy from array
} else  {
    echo none
}
```

Comment: I don't know why formating has messed up :L

Comment: You can click 'edit' and fix it.

Comment: Have a look at PHP operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP IF statement for Boolean values: $var === true vs $var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670138/php-if-statement-for-boolean-values-var-true-vs-var)

Comment: It's not because I want to know how to do this instead of which one is faster..

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if your variable contains a boolean, all you have to do is:

```
if($myVar)
{
    //do stuff
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

You can also do this if it's clearer to you:

```
if($myVar == true)
{
    //do stuff
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

What's important is not to mistake the comparison operator (==) with the assignment (=) otherwise you'll end up with strange results. This happened in your initial statement in which you also forgot the parenthesis.

As for the "else" statement, it is automatically executed when the condition is false, which in this case would mean $myVar is actually false.

Comment: Add details on his mistake so this post can help others (comparison of a boolean as a string)

Comment: How would it ever do the else statement?

Comment: You will never get in the if statement if you compare it to the string 'True' neither. You will always get true on the other hand with this syntax '$var = true' because the affectation will occur.