# TinyMCE Contents not submitting to Database PHP and MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So basic text does submit fine (like making it bold)

The problem: When I try to do anything else like changing the font family, highlighting, changing text color, things like that - The form doesn't submit as if the $_POST is blank

**What doesn't work:**

- Change text color to Red
- Click Submit button
- $_POST is not set and not true, so nothing happens. Page just refreshes and nothing submits as if $_POST['frontpagetext'] is null/false

**What works fine:**

- Type in regular text like "hello world"
- Click Submit Button
- $_POST is set and is true, coding fires, saves to database, success message displayed and data is saved successfully

**What I have tried:**

- Changed database to utf8mb4, this at least fixed the emoticons... But didn't fix anything else
- Tried other editors like Ckeditor, etc, same results

My HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="frontpagetext" class="editor"><?php echo $customizeinfo['front_text']; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-end" value="Save Text" />
</form>
```

My javascript:

```
tinymce.init({
        entity_encoding: 'raw',
        selector: 'textarea',
        file_picker_types: 'file image media',
        image_advtab: true,
        image_uploadtab: false,
        images_file_types: 'jpg,jpeg',
        images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
        plugins: 'autoresize emoticons image textcolor colorpicker hr link table lists advlist contextmenu',
        menubar: '',
        toolbar: 'styleselect | undo redo | bold italic underline | link image | forecolor backcolor | hr | table',
        contextmenu: "bold italic underline | bullist numlist | link | cell row column deletetable",
        image_caption: true,
        style_formats: [
            {title: 'Image Left', selector: 'img', styles: {
                'float' : 'left',
                'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
            }},
            {title: 'Image Right', selector: 'img', styles: {
                'float' : 'right',
                'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
            }},
            { title: 'Encabezado', 
                block: 'h2', 
                styles: {   'color': '#0871ad' } 
                },
            { title: 'Texto Resaltado', 
                inline: 'span', 
                styles: {   'color': '#000000', 'background-color': '#f6f433' } 
            }
        ],
    });
```

My PHP:

```
if ($_POST['frontpagetext']==true) {
    $newtext=$_POST['frontpagetext'];

    $query = $dbpdo->query(
    "UPDATE lal_website_conf
    SET front_text = ?, updated_at = ?
    WHERE id = ?",
    $newtext,
    $databasedate,
    $currentID
    );

    if (!$query) {
        $error_header="Error Saving Changes";
        $error_msg= "Server encountered an error.<br /><br /> Please notify site admin";
    } else {
        $speed="fast";
        $success_header="Saved!";
        $success_msg= "Changes have been saved and is live on your site!";
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any middleware enabled? like xssprotection? some of them can interfere with html tag when submitting.

Comment: @Mashtan unfortunately I don't have middleware, it's a core PHP project - unless Apache has something?

Comment: ok.....are you sure the bold tags are getting through? do you see <b>Mytext<b> in your database if you input Mytext in bold format?

Comment: Yes the <b> tags go through, but the other tags keep it from submitting, like <font>

Comment: `$query` is a misnomer. It's actually the result.

Comment: You may find PHP easier to pick up and be effective for building applications if you to look at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) first to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Comment: Check with the Network inspector in your browser to see what was submitted. `var_dump` what you received to see what you got server-side. Somewhere along the way there's something that's not connected properly. One thing that strikes me as obviously wrong is you test `$_POST['frontpagetext']==true` and then go and do `$newtext=$_POST['frontpagetext'];` which means it just be `true`, and isn't actually the text at all. Are you trying to test "if parameter was set/given/is non-zero-length?"

Comment: @tadman I've already tried them all and they're more frustrating then what I'm doing

Comment: @tadman if it's true then it sets the variable, if it's not true then the code doesn't even run because it's as if the form didn't submit. This has worked fine for everything I do including complicated coding. It just means that the $_POST is not true, meaning something is wrong with the textarea when I put complicated formatting

Comment: I think as a better test, I'll copy what's in the source of tinymce and paste it into a regular textarea... If that submits to the database then I know the issue is with tinymce

Comment: The `== true` part is not a great way to assert something exists. Maybe [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)?

Comment: Here's my advice. If you're using version control, and you better be, start *deleting things*. Remove anything and everything until all you have left is the exact problem you're trying to fix. For example, make your goal being to just show, on screen, the received content. Fix that and you can reassemble it back into the prior, broken version.

Comment: @tadman it is usually isset, I changed it to ==true for testing and it'll be isset when I'm done. I'm trying to see if the $_POST is true in the first place, which it's not. But yeah I'll do that, I'll also submit with a regular textarea and see what that does. Thanks

Comment: Honestly that `"x"==true` in PHP is just downright bizarre and is not something that expresses, reasonably, what you're intending.

Comment: @tadman Uhhh, "X"==true allows you to check if there is a value inside of $_POST... Do you not understand core PHP or something?

Comment: @tadman Using if ($var === true) or if ($var) is not a question of style but a question of correctness. Because if ($var) is the same as if ($var == true). And == comparison doesn’t check the type. So 1 == true is true, but 1 === true is false.... Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670138/php-if-statement-for-boolean-values-var-true-vs-var

Comment: It's not that I don't understand PHP, it's that there's some PHP-isms that are just so maddeningly weird that they read as outright nonsense if you're not thinking in a pure PHP mindset. If you have to flip back and forth between PHP and JavaScript, for example, you're going to need a second to focus on this code before it makes any sense at all. The intent is muddled.